# How to safely read an unsigned int from a stream?

Tags: c++, iostream

In the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("-89");
    std::cout << static_cast<bool>(iss) << iss.good() << iss.fail() << iss.bad() << iss.eof() << '\n';
    unsigned int u;
    iss >> u;
    std::cout << static_cast<bool>(iss) << iss.good() << iss.fail() << iss.bad() << iss.eof() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

the streams lib reads a signed value into an `unsigned int` without even a hiccup, silently [producing a wrong result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8195ba8f3bfb675):

```
11000
10001
```

We need to be able to catch those runtime type mismatch errors. If we hadn't just caught this in a simulation, this could have blown up very expensive hardware.

*How can we safely read an unsigned value from a stream?*

Comment: have a look at boost::numerical_cast http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html

Comment: Wow, TIL and it's only morning.

Comment: What should be expected output of this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read into a variable of a signed type that can handle the entire range first and test if it is negative or beyond the maximum of your target type. If your unsigned values may not fit into the largest signed type available, you'll have to do parsing using something other than iostreams.

Answer (score 11):

You could write a manipulator:

```
template <typename T>
struct ExtractUnsigned
{
    T& value;
    ExtractUnsigned(T& value) : value(value) {}
    void read(std::istream& stream) const {
        char c;
        stream >> c;
        if(c == '-') throw std::runtime_error("Invalid unsigned number");
        stream.putback(c);
        stream >> value;
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline ExtractUnsigned<T> extract_unsigned(T& value) {
    return ExtractUnsigned<T>(value);
}

template <typename T>
inline std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& stream, const ExtractUnsigned<T>& extract) {
    extract.read(stream);
    return stream;
}


int main()
{
    std::istringstream data("   +89   -89");
    unsigned u;
    data >> extract_unsigned(u);
    std::cout << u << '\n';
    data >> extract_unsigned(u);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does this also work if there are spaces before the `-` ?

Comment: @stijn Yes it is formatted input

Answer (score 5):

First off, I think parsing a negative value for an `unsigned` value is wrong. The value is decoded by `std::num_get<char>` according to the format of `strtoull()` (22.4.2.12 paragraph 3, stage 3, second bullet). The format of `strtoull()` is defined in C 7.22.1.4 to be the same as for integer constants in C 6.4.4.1 which requires that the literal value can be represented by an `unsigned` type. Clearly, a negative value cannot be represented by an `unsigned` type. Admittedly, I looked at C11 which I isn't really the C standard referenced from C++11. Also, quoting standard paragraphs at the compiler won't fix the issue. Hence, below is an approach which neatly changes the decoding of the values.

You could set up a global `std::locale` with a `std::num_get<...>` facet rejecting strings starting with a minus sign for `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`. The `do_put()` override could simply check the first character and then delegate to the base class version if it isn't a `'-'`.

Below is the code for a custom facet. Although it is quite a bit of code, the actual use is rather straight forward. Most of the code is just boilerplate overriding the different `virtual` functions used to parse an `unsigned` number (i.e., the `do_get()` members). These are all just implemented in terms of the member function template `get_impl()` which checks if there are no more characters or if the next character is a `'-'`. In either of these two cases the conversion fails by adding `std::ios_base::failbit` to the parameter `err`. Otherwise, the function merely delegates to the base class conversion.

The correspondingly created facet is eventually used to construct a new `std::locale` object (`custom`; note that the allocated `positive_num_get` object is automatically release when the last `std::locale` object where it is used is released). This `std::locale` is installed to become the global locale. The global locale is used by all newly created stream. Existing streams, in the example `std::cin` need to be `imbue()`d with the locale if it should affect them. Once the global locale is set up, newly created stream will just pick up the changed decoding rules, i.e., there shouldn't be much need to change code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>

class positive_num_get
    : public std::num_get<char> {
    typedef std::num_get<char>::iter_type iter_type;
    typedef std::num_get<char>::char_type char_type;

    // actual implementation: if there is no character or it is a '-' fail
    template <typename T>
    iter_type get_impl(iter_type in, iter_type end,
                       std::ios_base& str, std::ios_base::iostate& err,
                       T& val) const {
        if (in == end || *in == '-') {
            err |= std::ios_base::failbit;
            return in;
        }
        else {
            return this->std::num_get<char>::do_get(in, end, str, err, val);
        }
    }
    // overrides of the various virtual functions
    iter_type do_get(iter_type in, iter_type end,
                     std::ios_base& str, std::ios_base::iostate& err,
                     unsigned short& val) const override {
        return this->get_impl(in, end, str, err, val);
    }
    iter_type do_get(iter_type in, iter_type end,
                     std::ios_base& str, std::ios_base::iostate& err,
                     unsigned int& val) const override {
        return this->get_impl(in, end, str, err, val);
    }
    iter_type do_get(iter_type in, iter_type end,
                     std::ios_base& str, std::ios_base::iostate& err,
                     unsigned long& val) const override {
        return this->get_impl(in, end, str, err, val);
    }
    iter_type do_get(iter_type in, iter_type end,
                     std::ios_base& str, std::ios_base::iostate& err,
                     unsigned long long& val) const override {
        return this->get_impl(in, end, str, err, val);
    }
};

void read(std::string const& input)
{
    std::istringstream in(input);
    unsigned long value;
    if (in >> value) {
        std::cout << "read " << value << " from '" << input << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "failed to read value from '" << input << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    read("\t 17");
    read("\t -18");

    std::locale custom(std::locale(), new positive_num_get);
    std::locale::global(custom);
    std::cin.imbue(custom);

    read("\t 19");
    read("\t -20");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
        std::istringstream iss("-89");
        std::cout << static_cast<bool>(iss) << iss.good() << iss.fail() << iss.bad() << iss.eof() << '\n';
        int u;
        if ((iss >> u) && (u > 0)) {
                unsigned int u1 = static_cast<unsigned int>(u);
                std::cout << "No errors: " << u1 << std::endl;
        } else {
                std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << static_cast<bool>(iss) << iss.good() << iss.fail() << iss.bad() << iss.eof() << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn’t work for all values. In particular, the value of `static_cast<unsigned>(-1)` would yield a wrong result (anything with the highest bit set, actually).

Comment: @KonradRudolph what about `u > 0`?

Comment: @Bartek The point is that it’s *not* an error.